# How can I determine the average of last 3 values for each user?

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

Hello the question I'm working on is:

Determine for each customer the average of the last three order values.

I've tried this

```
SELECT AVG(value) AS the_average
FROM (SELECT value FROM sales ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 9)
```

| cust | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 2019-12-03 | 8 |
| 101 | 2019-12-07 | 5 |
| 102 | 2019-12-15 | 3 |
| 102 | 2019-12-17 | 5 |
| 103 | 2019-12-22 | 8 |
| 103 | 2020-01-02 | 2 |
| 103 | 2020-01-04 | 10 |
| 103 | 2020-01-10 | 5 |
| 102 | 2020-01-15 | 6 |
| 101 | 2020-01-19 | 2 |
| 101 | 2020-02-02 | 4 |
| 101 | 2020-02-04 | 5 |
| 103 | 2020-02-12 | 4 |
| 102 | 2020-02-15 | 5 |

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
    with cte as (
        SELECT  
            cust, value, row_number() over(partition by cust order by date desc) num
        from 
            your_table 
    ),
cte2 as (
    select * from cte where num <4 
)
    select cust, avg(value)
    from cte2
    group by cust
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get only for cust 101 the average by doing this.

Comment: I updated my answer, could you try again?

Comment: Thank you very much. It's correct now!

Answer (score 0):

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table table_name(cust int, date date, value int);

 insert into table_name values(102, '2019-12-03',   8);
 insert into table_name values(101, '2019-12-07',   5);
 insert into table_name values(102, '2019-12-15',   3);
 insert into table_name values(102, '2019-12-17',   5);
 insert into table_name values(103, '2019-12-22',   8);
 insert into table_name values(103, '2020-01-02',   2);
 insert into table_name values(103, '2020-01-04',  10);
 insert into table_name values(103, '2020-01-10',   5);
 insert into table_name values(102, '2020-01-15',   6);
 insert into table_name values(101, '2020-01-19',   2);
 insert into table_name values(101, '2020-02-02',   4);
 insert into table_name values(101, '2020-02-04',   5);
 insert into table_name values(103, '2020-02-12',   4);
 insert into table_name values(102, '2020-02-15',   5);
```

Query:

```
  with CTE as (
         SELECT  
             cust, value, row_number() over(partition by cust order by date desc) rn
         from 
             table_name
     )
     select cust, avg(value)
     from CTE
     where rn<=3
     group by cust
```

Output:

| cust | avg(value) |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 3.6666666666667 |
| 102 | 5.3333333333333 |
| 103 | 6.3333333333333 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2d41e3ac22e08531408f0a4e948e7d56)*

Comment: Thank you very much for your input sir! It's correct!

Comment: @Kaffo you are most welcome. Best wishes.